# Postgresql inner join (especially self join) on many columns optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, query-optimization

I am running PostgresSQL 9.6.2 and have a table with 7 columns with about 2,900,000 rows. The table is temporary, and it's a part of subject deduplication process, which aims to assign new id (s_id_new) to subjects which are the same, based on different set of rules. In total, I perform inner join about 10-12 times, each time on similar, yet slightly different subset of the data / different WHERE conditions / different join columns.

Right now, the query is so inefficient, that it didn't complete (had to cancel it after 2 hours).

For the purpose of the optimization I created a subset of the data (50 000 rows).

```
\d subject_subset;
     Column     |          Type          | Modifiers
----------------+------------------------+-----------
 s_id           | text                   |
 surname_clean  | character varying(20)  |
 name_clean     | character varying(20)  |
 fullname_clean | character varying(100) |
 id1            | character varying(20)  |
 id2            | character varying(20)  |
 id3            | character varying(20)  |
 s_id_new       | character varying(20)  |
Indexes:
    "subject_subset_s_id_new_idx" btree (s_id_new)
```

The query I'm trying to optimize

```
select s_id_new, max(I_s_id) as s_id_deduplicated
from (select a.*, b.s_id_new as I_s_id
                from public.subject_subset  a
                inner join public.subject_subset b on a.surname_clean=b.surname_clean
                and a.id2=b.id2
                where
                    a.id1 is null 
                    and a.id2 is not null 
                    and a.surname_clean is not null ) h
 group by s_id_new;



The result of the EXPLAIN ANALYZE:
https://explain.depesz.com/s/7knH

"GroupAggregate  (cost=5616.65..5620.39 rows=142 width=90) (actual time=32542.127..46938.858 rows=2889 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: a.s_id_new"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=5616.65..5617.42 rows=310 width=116) (actual time=32542.116..43194.626 rows=18356220 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: a.s_id_new"
"        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 531760kB"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=1114.72..5603.82 rows=310 width=116) (actual time=13.159..4892.011 rows=18356220 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: (((b.surname_clean)::text = (a.surname_clean)::text) AND ((b.id2)::text = (a.id2)::text))"
"              ->  Seq Scan on subject_subset b  (cost=0.00..1111.00 rows=50000 width=174) (actual time=0.011..10.775 rows=50000 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=1111.00..1111.00 rows=248 width=174) (actual time=13.137..13.137 rows=15044 loops=1)"
"                    Buckets: 16384 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1151kB"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on subject_subset a  (cost=0.00..1111.00 rows=248 width=174) (actual time=0.005..9.330 rows=15044 loops=1)"
"                          Filter: ((id1 IS NULL) AND (id2 IS NOT NULL) AND (surname_clean IS NOT NULL))"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 34956"
"Planning time: 0.236 ms"
"Execution time: 47013.839 ms"
```

As far as I can see it's the SORT of the subquery that's causing the problems, consuming LOTS of space when the full table is sorted, but I can not figure out how to optimize it.

The only thing that brought slight improvement of performance was assigning new integer ID's with dense_rank, but it's not enough.

Comment: It would help if you explain in words what goal this specific query is trying to accomplish.  Otherwise we have to try to guess the task based on the query.

Comment: The query aims to deduplicate subjects - companies and natural persons - to assign them the same ID. Two Jonh Smiths having same document ID  have different ID in the database (s_id) -> Code assigns them a new ID = maximum of s_id's he has now. Sometimes auxiliary data is used for the deduplication (addresses, phones, etc), but idea stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

The large sort is killing you.

I have three suggestions:

1. Run `ANALYZE subject_subset` to collect table statistics for the table.
   Statistics are not automatically collected for temporary tables, and the estimates are quite off in your case.

   Maybe that is enough to make it better!
2. Try an index on `(id2, surname_clean, s_id_new)`, that would help with a nested loop join (don't know if that's faster though).

   You could try a lateral join like

   ```
   SELECT a.s_id_new,
          max(b.i_s_id) AS s_id_deduplicated
   FROM subject_subset a
      CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT s_id_new AS i_s_id
                          FROM subject_subset
                          WHERE a.surname_clean = surname_clean
                            AND a.id2 = id2
                          ORDER BY s_id_new DESC
                          LIMIT 1
                         ) b
   GROUP BY a.s_id_new;
   ```

   The nested loop join will be expensive, but the sort should be fast.
3. Stick with a hash join, but reduce the number of rows:

   ```
   SELECT a.s_id_new,
          max(b.i_s_id) AS s_id_deduplicated
   FROM subject_subset a
      JOIN (SELECT surname_clean, id2,
                   max(s_id_new) AS i_s_id
            FROM subject_subset
            GROUP BY surname_clean, id2
           ) b
         USING (surname_clean, id2)
   WHERE a.id1 IS NULL 
     AND a.id2 IS NOT NULL
     AND a.surname_clean IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY a.s_id_new;
   ```

   Maybe an index on `(surname_clean, id2)` can help, not sure.